# Better way to move objects from one std::deque to another?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

If I have two `std::deque`s, and I want to move the first `n` objects from the beginning of one to the beginning of the other, what is the best way to do that?  Doing the following:

```
template <typename T>
void fn(std::deque<T>& src)
{
  std::deque<T> storage;
  size_t i = /* some calculated value between 0 and src.size() */;
  storage.insert(storage.begin(), src.begin(), src.begin()+i);
  src.erase(src.begin(), src.begin()+i);

  // ... other stuff ...
}
```

would create copies of the T objects.  I guess I could do something like (not tested, as example only):

```
template <typename T>
void fn(std::deque<T>& src)
{
  std::deque<T> storage;
  size_t i = /* some calculated value between 0 and src.size() */;
  for (auto& it = std::reverse_iterator<decltype(src.begin()>(src.begin()+i)
    ; it != std::reverse_iterator<decltype<src.begin()>(src.begin())
    ; ++it)
  {
    storage.push_front(std::move(*it));
  }
  src.erase(src.begin(), src.begin()+i);

  // ... other stuff ...
}
```

but I'm wondering, is there an algorithm that would already handle this?

Comment: You can store pointers so there would be no need to create temporaries or move stored objects. Even better would be some sort of intrusive `deque`, however standard library does not provide one.

Comment: [`std::move`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move) and `src.erase(...)`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use a move iterator by calling [`std::make_move_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/make_move_iterator):

```
storage.insert(storage.begin(),
  std::make_move_iterator(src.begin()),
  std::make_move_iterator(src.begin()+i));

src.erase(src.begin(), src.begin()+i);
```